# Accidently unmounted a local folder

Tags: mount, directory, local

After that I tried to `mount` the folder via its full name (/var/...), but the console is saying: `mount: can't find /var/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/ in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Thanks for your help,
Nicolas.

**EDIT:** to complete my issue, I can actually see the unmounted folder, but I can't upload via FTP anyfile in it, although creating files via the console (touch test) does work.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How exactly have you tried to remount your folder?

Comment: Also maybe let us know what OS you're using, might just help...

Comment: Linux? Solaris? BSD? Which version? OK its not vfstab so its not Solaris...

Comment: Chances are the mount point of the folder you want is a parent of the folder, and not the folder itself, and/or you need to specify the partition being mounted.

Comment: Hi, the OS is a debian. I can't see how more specific I could as it is exactly everything that has happened. Cheers.

Comment: @kmarsh, BSDs don't use mtab, so it's a Linux flavor.

Comment: @Nicolas You could be more specific, for instance, by telling us which command you typed when you tried to mount your folder. If you typed something like "mount -t ext3 -o defaults /var/foo/bar /my/folder" the error message you provided is actually a weird one. If, otherwise, you just used "mount /var/foo/bar" and the directory /var/foo/bar is not mapped into your /etc/fstab, well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-Platform Compatible Method:
If it's one of the normal mount points, just reboot and it'll fix itself.

Most *nix OSes:
Run `mount -a` and it will automount all the default mount points.

If it's not a default mount point (in fstab or mtab):
You'll have to manually mount it again; you must have manually mounted it once, so just do the same thing again.

Comment: Hi, I tried the mount -a, but the problem is still there. Actually to be more precise, I can see and go into the directory, but there's nothing in it even if I move some files to (using an FTP protocol). Cheers.

Comment: Mount takes two arguments normally, a block device argument and mounts it to a folder argument. For example `mount /dev/da0s1a /mnt` works for me (your block device would be different). If the folder is listed in fstab then you can cheat and only give mount the folder argument; it will look up the device in the fstab file.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to specify and I tried without a second argment, but as it is a folder within sda1, what shoulb it be then? Is there any way to know "where" it has been unmounted?

Comment: Alright, so actually, the mount-a seemed to has solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact syntax of the mount command you used to attempt a remount?  IIRC, your partition to directory mapping varies from distro to distro in Unix environments, meaning `/var/` can be on a separate partition or just under `/` with other directories on the same partition.  Your setup may vary, but I have not seen a popularish distro where the a sub-directoyr of `/var/` is mounted separate, but that does not mean much.  What are other things are in your fstab config?

Comment: Hi, I did a : mount /var/www/folder/subfoler which lead to this result. Cheers.